# Vue2 understanding :class attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So, I was watching [vue2](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/5?autoplay=true) tutorial, when I found this piece of code which I don't understand why and how it really works.

Here is a style:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .is-loading { background: red }
</style>
```

and the html:

```
<div id="root">
<button :class="{ 'is-loading': isLoading }" @click="toggleClass"> Toggle Me</button>
</div>
```

and vue code:

```
new Vue({
   el: '#root', 
   data: {
      isLocading: false
   },
   methods: {
        toggleClass: function(){
            this.isLoading = !this.isLoading;
        }
   }
});
```

Now, this code toggles the class name for the button when clicked, but what I don't understand is the `{ 'is-loading': isLoading }` part, which does not seem to be a ternary operator.

What exactly is it saying? the class name is **already** mentioned first as `is-loading` but the variable appears after it.

Shouldn't this look like `{ variable ? 'class' ? 'no-class' }` in other words, shouldn't the variable appear first, then the class?

Comment: It's just adds the classe if **isLoading === true**

Comment: I know if adds the classes if `isLoading === true` but, why does it appear in the order it does?

Comment: What appear in the order? What is that thing? The **{ 'is-loading': isLoading }** is an object, :class only check if the property is true and then apply It's name, the class to the element.

Comment: Vue created its own DSL. So you saw HTML, it's actually not. It's a DSL looks like HTML.

Comment: What I am saying is that, why does it appear from right to left? I mean the evaluation? Almost always, we evaluate expressions as `if-true : 'somevalue'` but in this case it appears the other way around like `somvalue : if-true` @Fals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue.js has the ability to run [Javascript expressions within all data-binding areas](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions).

This is a little bit of Vue.js magic happening in the background, but you can think of it essentially like this:

1. Vue sees the `:` on `class=` specifying a data-binding
2. Vue looks to see what's inside of the `class=` attribute, and sees the following: `{ 'is-loading': isLoading }`
3. Vue notices it's an object, so it walks through each key/value pair and evaluates it, if the value (`isLoading` in this case) is true, it adds the key (`is-loading`) to the class attribute, or not if the value is false.

Vue CAN interpret ternaries within the data-binding syntax, but this is a bit of Vue's internal magic that allows you to easily create multiple UI state variations for a component with very little effort.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why does this particular code evaluate from right to left? I

Comment: Well, technically, it's not evaluating right to left. Vue sees it's a JS object inside of a class attribute, so it identifies the key `is-loading`, and then asks what to do with it by looking at the value `isLoading`.

Comment: I understand it now, with that comment. It seems strange a bit strange though, which also means you can't set a class name with value of `false` hypothetically speaking, since vue will hide everything if it is false.

Comment: Well, you could actually set it as false if you wanted to,  you'd just need to make it a string value in the key rather than a boolean:

`:class={ 'false': isLoading }`

Modern JS patterns would probably recommend doing something like this though:

`:class="{ 'is-false': isLoading }`